# Trying to replace strings in a file but its replacing too much

Tags: string, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to put together a PowerShell script to run through txt log files and remove domain names / urls.

So  far I am just doing a find replace on the files but when I try this it is not working the way I expect e.g.

if I have a text file containing:

> intranet.contoso.com and some text

after running my script to replace intranet.contoso.com with DOMAIN1  the out put I would get is

> DOMAIN1 DOMAIN1aDOMAIN1nDOMAIN1dDOMAIN1 DOMAIN1sDOMAIN1oDOMAIN1mDOMAIN1eDOMAIN1 DOMAIN1tDOMAIN1eDOMAIN1xDOMAIN1tDOMAIN1

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My code so far is

```
$domains = ,("mydomain.net","mydomain"),("yourdomain.net","yourdomain"),("mydomain2.net","mydomain2")
$path = Read-Host "Please enter the full path to the directory containing the files to be sanatized"

    $files = Get-ChildItem –Path $path *.txt
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        for($x=0; $x -lt $domains.Count; $x++)
        {
            (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
            Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $domains[$x][0], "DOMAIN$($x+1)" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath

            (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
            Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $domains[$x][1], "DOMAIN$($x+1)" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure your main issue is the use of the [unary operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) when you are defining `$domains`. If you look at your first element.

```
PS D:\temp> $domains[0]
mydomain.net
mydomain
```

Which you would have expected but its the next step where the issue happens. Lets try and get the "mydomain" string

```
PS D:\temp> $domains[0][1]
```

Nothing? That is odd. No not really if you know what has happened. Lets look at the other element of this jagged array.

```
PS D:\temp> $domains[0][0]
mydomain.net
mydomain
```

What is this nonsense? The first element of the first element of your array is another array. Now watch this:

```
PS D:\temp> $domains[0][0][1]
mydomain
```

There is the element we were trying to get a couple of steps ago. You made an array where the first element was an array containing a array of two elements.

The reason your test file looks the way it did is that the first example would have tried to use `$domains[0][1]` which would be null and match every space between characters hence your output.

Simple remove the unary operator.

```
$domains = ("mydomain.net","mydomain"),("yourdomain.net","yourdomain"),("mydomain2.net","mydomain2")
```

---

Also worth noting that `-replace` is a regex operator so you need to be careful using meta-characters in your matching strings. Period for example. The static regex method escape can solve this issue for you to ensure your strings are matched literally.

```
$_ -replace [regex]::Escape($domains[$x][1]), "DOMAIN$($x+1)"
```

---

You can also improve you replacement logic knowing that `-replace` is also an array operator. So inside your loop you can replace this

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $domains[$x][0], "DOMAIN$($x+1)" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath

(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $domains[$x][1], "DOMAIN$($x+1)" } |
Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

With this.

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace $domains[$x][0], "DOMAIN$($x+1)"  -replace $domains[$x][1], "DOMAIN$($x+1)" |
Set-Content $file
```

`.pspath` while valid is not required. The cmdlets `Get/Set-Content` will match the path by parameter name from the `$file` object. I can't really help more than that. This is untested as I don't have good sample text files handy. Test and test some more to be sure.

Comment: I'm fairly new to powershell so this has helped me in more ways than one! cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're having is the way your creating your multidimensional array. When I used your line I got something very different.

try rewriting the first line to this (an array of arrays):

```
$domains = @(@("mydomain.net","mydomain"),@("yourdomain.net","yourdomain"),@("mydomain2.net","mydomain2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other two answers point out, the array-of-arrays is getting confused with the `,(x,y,),(foo,bar)" syntax. Use of`@` or simply dropping the leading comma fixes that.

I've also found that the writing to the same file as you're reading from is not working well for me, even with the `(Get-Content $file.PSPath)` syntax. I'm getting more consistent results by writing to a new file then renaming later.

Comment: This is not the issue. That should just be sending an array of strings down the pipeline. The issue is `$domains` the regex is matching `$nulls` which is why the replace it happening every space. The first `$domains[0][1]` is $null.

Comment: That'll teach me for thinking in C#. `Get-Content` decomposes line-wise, not character-wise. Right, I'll overclock the old biological CPU and get back soon

Comment: Completely rewrote answer. Matt's answer is on the money though.

Comment: `(Get-Content $file) | set-content $file` should work because the brackets cause the hole file to be sent down the pipe _after_ the handle is closed. Remove the brackets and it will send the first string down the pipe and error out since the file is still open for reading at the time it is trying to write.

Comment: Yes it should. I can reproduce this correctly with example code. But when I run OPs code, it produces what he sees. When I change `Set-Content "$file.PSPath"` to `Set-Content "$($file.PSPath)1"` it looks far more sensible. And I have no explanation for that.